# Replacements in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, evaluation, hold

I would like to understand why this is not working:

```
replacement = {a[t] -> r};
Manipulate[Plot[a[t] /. replacement, {r, 0, 1}], {t, 1, 2}]
```

But this does:

```
Manipulate[Plot[a[t] /.{a[t] -> r}, {r, 0, 1}], {t, 1, 2}]
```

I suppose it has to do with the `HoldAll` Attribute of `Manipulate` but I am not sure and I also don't know how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `Manipulate` localizes its variables. It does this lexically, that is, the variables that appear in the actual text of the code body are localized, but not the ones that might appear when the code is evaluated. So the `t` in `replacement` is different than the `t` in the `Manipulate`.  Sometimes it is important to keep the variables localized, so it is usually better (less bug-prone) to avoid applying `Evaluate` to the body, just in case the variables are given global values at some point in the kernel session.

One alternative is to construct the expression within `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[Plot[a[t] /. replacement, {r, 0, 1}],
 {t, 1, 2},
 {{replacement, {a[t] -> r}}, ControlType -> None}]
```

Another is to construct them as functions and pass the `Manipulate` parameters:

```
replacement[t_] := {a[t] -> r};
Manipulate[Plot[a[t] /. replacement[t], {r, 0, 1}], {t, 1, 2}]
```

Or all parameters:

```
replacement[a_, t_, r_] := {a[t] -> r};
Manipulate[Plot[a[t] /. replacement[a, t, r], {r, 0, 1}], {t, 1, 2}]
```

Comment: @Downvoter, what's wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 3):

Try using `Evaluate` to force evaluation:

```
replacement = {a[t] -> r};
Manipulate[Evaluate[Plot[a[t] /. replacement, {r, 0, 1}]], {t, 1, 2}]
```

Comment: Note that this does not work if the replacement value depends on `t`; for example, `replacement = {a[t] -> r^t}`.